# Get nested params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form with nested params. In the following example, how do I get the "amount_whole" value in the controller?

```
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"KCmBI6RLh0LdUsM2r5H1vhNykS1IXecFe5Lct+TuIGc=", "dec_declaration"=>{"declaration_nr"=>"SAL_2012_0001", "dec_declarationlines_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"amount_whole"=>"75"}}
```

Is it like this?

```
amount = params[:dec_declarations][:dec_declarationlines_attributes][:amount_whole]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot the `"0"` index in the hash. So you should be able to access it like this:

```
amount = params[:dec_declaration][:dec_declarationlines_attributes]["0"][:amount_whole]
```

The params hash works with both symbols and strings as keys.

### Edit

However, judging buy the structure of the params it looks like you have a model called DecDeclaration which has_many DecDeclarationlines and accepts_nested_attributes for that association. So you should be able to use it like this in the controller:

```
@dec_declaration = DecDeclaration.build(params[:dec_declaration])
@amount_whole = @dec_declaration.dec_declarationlines.first.amount_whole
```

Because if the params comes in that structure, it will automatically assign the nested values to the association.

Comment: how to do same like this in the  model?

Comment: In the model you first use `has_many :other_models` and then `accepts_nested_attributes_for :other_models`. Once that is done, you can use the form helper `f.fields_for :other_models do |other_form|` in your views