# Rails - set default for nested model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm building a nested model form that will allow a client to register (client model) and create a login (user model) at the same time. However, for new registrants, I would like to set the user.role_code (say to "A" for admin), but I've been struggling with this. From a data model perspective, and client has multiple users, since after registration, the client can access the app to add other users. From that perpective, I don't think I can default user_role in the model, since for added users, their role_code may be different. I would like to set the default in the controller.

Also, after form submission, users are sent as an array, so I would like to ensure only ONE user array object is sent upon registration (clearly for vulnerability reasons).

Here's my code

```
#client registration form new.html
<%= form_for @client do |client_form| %>
.....
    <%= client_form.fields_for :users do |user_form| %>
        <div class="field">
            <%= user_form.label :first_name %>
            <%= user_form.text_field :first_name %>
        </div>  
.....       
#client Controller

  def create
    logger.info params.inspect
    @client = Client.new(params[:client])

    if @client.save
    ......   

#client model
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :business_name, ... #and more
  attr_accessible :users_attributes

  has_many :users
  has_many :items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, allow_destroy: true

#logger.info params.inspect
"...users_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"first_name"=>..."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!!! After much researching, Googling, pulling out my hair, and lastly coming across [Get nested params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596238/get-nested-params), the answer is as follows:

```
@client.users.first.role_code = "A"
```

and to test the number of user array objects, use the following

```
if @client.users.size != 1
...
end
```